# Constrained heterogeneous list

Tags: haskell, types, hlist, constraint-kinds

I searched Hackage and couldn't find anything like the following but it seems to be fairly simple and useful. Is there a library that contains sort of data type?

```
data HList c where
  (:-) :: c a => a -> HList c
  Nil :: HList c
```

All the HLists I found could have any type, and weren't constrained.

If there isn't I'll upload my own.

Comment: I haven't seen one either. I've worked on something like that a while ago, but I never had it in a form where I felt like it should be uploaded. [Also, you can run into some weird corners of the type system exploring this](https://github.com/roboguy13/existentialist/blob/master/src/Data/Existentialist.hs#L67).

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure this data type is useful...

- If you really want `a` to be existentially qualified, I think you should use regular lists. The more interesting data type here would be `Exists`, although I'm certain there are variants of it all over <s>package</s> Hackage already:

  ```
  data Exists c where
    Exists :: c a => a -> Exists c
  ```

  Then, your `HList c` is isomorphic to `[Exists c]` and you can still use all of the usual list based functions.
- On the other hand, if you don't necessarily want `a` in the `(:-) :: c a => a -> HList c` to be existentially qualified (having it as such sort of defies the point of the `HList`), you should instead define the following:

  ```
  data HList (as :: [*]) where
    (:-) :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)
    Nil :: HList '[]
  ```

  Then, if you want to require that all entries of the `HList` satisfy `c`, you can make a type class to witness the injection from `HList as` into `[Exists c]` whose instance resolution only works if all the types in the `HList` satisfy the constraint:

  ```
  class ForallC as c where
    asList :: HList as -> [Exists c]

  instance ForallC '[] c where
    asList Nil = []

  instance (c a, ForallC as c) => ForallC (a ': as) c where
    asList (x :- xs) = Exists x : asList xs
  ```

Comment: A related question, is "Exists" anywhere? I've uploaded "polydata" which is basically "Exists", but I might as well someone else's package if it already exists to save duplication https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polydata-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Poly.html

Comment: It's old but searching around there appears to be a package called [`exists`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exists-0.2/docs/Data-Exists.html)...

Comment: Oh hang on, Exists and Poly are different.

Comment: @Alec To construct `Exists c` you need to find a single example `a` such that `c a`. To construct `Poly c` you must show that an `a` exists for all `a` such that `c a`. I think the terminology is `Exists` is "existentially quantified" and `Poly` is "universally quantified".

Comment: @Cirdec thanks! The haddock was tripping me up. Looking at the source code, I see what you mean.

Comment: I [asked about whether your `Exists` type is in a library somewhere on IRC some time ago](http://tunes.org/~nef/logs/haskell/17.01.25) (conversation starts around 21:34). At that time nobody knew of a place that offered it, but folks did suggest some [cute](http://lpaste.net/351658) [ideas](https://github.com/glguy/operations).

Comment: Why not use a type family to build the constraint `All c as` (`All c '[] = (); All c (a ': as) = (c a, All c as)`) rather than converting from `Hlist as` to `[Exist c]` which makes you lose information about the `as`?

Comment: @gallais Just a matter of taste. The problem with doing that is how to use 'All' afterwards.

Comment: @gallais Note that `ForallC as c` also holds exactly when `All c as` holds too - its just also lets you _do_ something with that information.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be able to do something with `All c as`. You'd access constraints just like you access values in an HList: using an index.

Comment: @gallais I'm not sure I see what you mean, but I wish I did because it sounds interesting. Do you have some example somewhere of how this works for `All` (or something similar)?

Comment: What about something like this? https://gist.github.com/gallais/48b6dba11b1fd57d4a7386cfe502ff94

Comment: @gallais Thanks! I see what you mean now. :)

Comment: I would argue that a type family `All` makes it much *easier* to actually use the constraints in practice than using just a type class. There's then no reason to first compute some term-level form where dictionaries are attached to values.

Comment: Quick update: a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/7056me/discovered_that_one_can_do_this_data_t_a_where_t/dn0iypo/) suggests the [exists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exists-0.2/docs/Data-Exists.html) package for your `Exists` type.

Comment: @DanielWagner That package was already linked to in the second comment. :)

Comment: @Alec Yeesh, I must be blind!

Answer (score 5):

The `generics-sop` package offers this out of the box.

A heterogeneous list can be defined in `generics-sop` by using

```
data NP :: (k -> *) -> [k] -> * where
  Nil  :: NP f '[]
  (:*) :: f x -> NP f xs -> NP f (x ': xs)
```

and instantiating it to the identity type constructor `I` (from `generics-sop`) or `Identity` (from `Data.Functor.Identity`).

The library then offers the constraint `All` such that e.g.

```
All Show xs => NP I xs
```

is the type of a heterogeneous list where all contained types are in the `Show` class. Conceptually, `All` is a type family that computes the constraint for every element in a type-level list:

```
type family All (f :: k -> Constraint) (xs :: [k]) :: Constraint where
  All c '[]       = ()
  All c (x ': xs) = (c x, All c xs)
```

(Only that in the actual definition, `All` is additionally wrapped in a type class so that it can be partially applied.)

The library furthermore offers all sorts of functions that traverse and transform `NP`s given a common constraint.

Answer (score 3):

What you really want is

```
data HKList :: (k -> *) -> [k] -> * where
  Nil  :: HKList f '[]
  (:*) :: f x -> HKList f xs -> HKList f (x ': xs)
```

Which you can use either as an ordinary heterogeneous list

```
type HList = HKList Identity
```

Or with extra information of some constant type `e` attached to each value (or other interesting functors)

```
HKList ((,) e)
```

Or with extra information captured in a dictionary

```
data Has c a where
    Has :: c a => a -> Has c a

type ConstrainedList c = HKList (Has c)
```

Or keep lists of only captured constraints

```
data Dict1 :: (k -> Constraint) -> k -> * where
  Dict1 :: c k => Dict1 c k
```

Which you can use to define the idea of all of a list of types satisfying a constraint

```
class All c xs where
  dicts :: HKList (Dict1 c) xs

instance All c '[] where
  dicts = Nil

instance (All c xs, c x) => All c (x ': xs) where
  dicts = Dict1 :* dicts
```

Or anything else you can do with a kind `k -> *`

You can freely convert between working with `All c xs => HList xs` and `HKList (Has c) xs`

```
zipHKList :: (forall k. f k -> g k -> h k) -> HKList f xs -> HKList g xs -> HKList h xs
zipHKList _ Nil Nil = Nil
zipHKList f (x :* xs) (y :* ys) = f x y :* zipHKList f xs ys

allToHas :: All c xs => HKList Identity xs -> HKList (Has c) xs
allToHas xs = zipHKList f dicts xs
  where
    f :: Dict1 c k -> Identity k -> Has c k
    f Dict1 (Identity x) = Has x

hasToAll :: HKList (Has c) xs -> Dict (All c xs)
hasToAll Nil = Dict
hasToAll (Has x :* xs) =
  case hasToAll xs of
    Dict -> Dict
```

[full code](https://gist.github.com/Cedev/415eecdc17bbdba9f6c25964c8ddb4e7)

I've written this a few times before for various projects, but I didn't know it was in a library anywhere until [Kosmikus pointed out that it's in `generics-sop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46169295/414413).

Comment: As discussed in the other answers, I think you'd be somewhat better off with turning `All` into a type family and not explicitly computing the `dicts`, but just using them directly. For this purpose, `generics-sop` offers "constrained" versions of functions such as your `zipHKList` that can use and distribute an `All` constraint over the elements.